# This probably involves the namespaces, but I can't figure what why the name is not found in one example, but is found in another

Tags: python, scope, namespaces

So I have two simple Python modules:
test1.py:

```
def main():
    def fmt(*args):
        r = ""
        for x in args:
            r += eval("f'"+x+"'")
        return r
    a = "alpha"
    b = "beta"
    d = "delta"
    msg = "Hello {d} one, this is {a} {b}"
    print(msg)
    print(fmt(msg))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And test2.py:

```
def fmt(*args):
    r = ""
    for x in args:
        r += eval("f'"+x+"'")
    return r
a = "alpha"
b = "beta"
d = "delta"
msg = "Hello {d} one, this is {a} {b}"
print(msg)
print(fmt(msg))
```

So, basically identical, except the first has the code wrapped in a function, while the second does not. The first, when executed, gives the following output:

```
Hello {d} one, this is {a} {b}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "test1.py", line 13, in main
    print(fmt(msg))
  File "test1.py", line 6, in fmt
    r += eval("f'"+x+"'")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

The second one does as I expected:

```
Hello {d} one, this is {a} {b}
Hello delta one, this is alpha beta
```

So the first one doesn't think it knows about the `d` name. But, if I insert `print(dir(d))` into test1.py right after the `def fmt(*args):` statement, now it finds `d`, and then doesn't know about the next name, `a`:

```
Hello {d} one, this is {a} {b}
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'capitalize', 'casefold', 'center', 'count', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'format_map', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isascii', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "test1.py", line 14, in main
    print(fmt(msg))
  File "test1.py", line 7, in fmt
    r += eval("f'"+x+"'")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

I'm sure someone understands what is happening, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, indeed, a matter of identifiers' scope. In your **test1.py**, the identifiers `a`, `b` and `d` are not known in the scope of the function `fmt`, because they are neither global (which is what makes them known in your **test2.py**), nor local. You can work around this by using the `nonlocal` statement inside `fmt`:

```
def main():
    def fmt(*args):
        nonlocal a, b, d # <----------- only added line of code
        r = ""
        for x in args:
            r += eval("f'"+x+"'")
        return r
    a = "alpha"
    b = "beta"
    d = "delta"
    msg = "Hello {d} one, this is {a} {b}"
    print(msg)
    print(fmt(msg))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks! @Dallan's comment also pointed in that same direction. Still, an ugly hack (IMO), because now I have to specify all the possible non-local variables that might go into the function, when all I want is for it to take the string and apply the formatting. Obviously, my application is more complex than this (much simplified) example. Thanks, again!